# 7Zip better strategy to compress one file in one 7z file by command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, 7zip

I wrote a Windows batch file to compress my original files in their folder and delete the originals, and it works fine:

```
@echo off
for /f %%x in ('dir /A:-d /s /b /ad') do (
    cd %%x
    for /f %%f in ('dir /A:-d /s /b') do (
        echo %%f
        7z.exe a -sdel -xr!*.7z "%%f.7z" "%%f"
    )
    cd ..
)
```

Is there a less verbose way to accomplish this task?

I've this folder structure:

```
c:\
\---joe
    +---a
    |      test1.txt
    |      test2.txt
    |
    +---b
    |      test3.txt
    |
    \---c
           test4.txt
```

My wished result is:

```
c:\
\---joe
    +---a
    |      test1.txt.7z
    |      test2.txt.7z
    |
    +---b
    |      test3.txt.7z
    |
    \---c
           test4.txt.7z
```

Comment: A single line should do: `for /r "C:\joe" %%a in (*.txt) do 7z.exe a -sdel -xr!*.7z "%%f.7z" "%%a"`

Comment: @Stephan: Hi dear, thanks for your reply but doesn't work. Has created a new 7z file in the root with two files of the first folder (a) and the other two are lost.

Comment: Just curious if you know what this is doing and why do you have it coded like this if you do? `dir /A:-d /s /b /ad`

Comment: @Squashman: The first for get me all subdirectories (plain), in the second apply a dire on the current subdir to get all files

Comment: @JoeTaras, I only asked you about the first one.  Did you notice you have `/A-D` and `/AD`?

Comment: @JoeTaras, did you notice the typo in Stephans code?  Since it is now only using one `FOR` command one of these has to change: `"%%f.7z" "%%a"`

Comment: @JoeTaras you may want to open up a command prompt and read the help file for the `FOR` command.  Especially the very last section about the `~` (command) modifiers. You may or may not need those to do it on a single line of code.

Comment: @Squashman: about Stephan typo I've no noticed. Now I try again.

Comment: @Squashman: Sorry, but I've re-ran the Stephan command but I've the same error. Maybe I don't understand the fix.

Comment: So you understand that when you initialize a `FOR` command your create a single letter meta-variable.  Stephan probably copy and pasted your original 7zip execution code and forgot to change `"%%f.7z"` to `"%%a.7z"`  Works no differently then all programming languages I have used a `FOR` command.  You need to be referencing the correct `FOR` variable that you created when the `FOR` command is executed.

Comment: @Squashman: Finally I've tested Stephan script with your adviced fix and work fine. If Stepahn convert his comment as answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single line should do:

```
for /r "C:\joe" %%a in (*.txt) do 7z.exe a -sdel -xr!*.7z "%%a.7z" "%%a"
```

`for /r "startfolder"` defines the start folder for recursive search.

Don't forget to provide the path to `7z.exe` if it isn't in the `%PATH%` or current directory.